# Companions Radiant Quests: No Quests Available?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've finished the last of the Companion Quests (Glory of the Dead) and am now the Harbinger. Since then, I've done one of the radiant quests from Farkas (or Vilkas--can't keep those guys straight).

Now, I have the Miscellaneous quest to ask one of the Companion leaders for work, but when I talk to any of them, there's no work option.

I thought I would at least be able to go retrieve some family's bow or kill a cave bear or something.  Is it broken or am I just missing some trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad.  Apparently, I only talked to Aela and Vilkas, and they never had the option to start a new quest.  I went back and talked to Farkas and he gave me a new quest.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one of those people tell me that X other person already has me on a quest, so that leads me in the right direction.

Also, if you have any of them as your follower, you need to send them home before the option for work becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

If you complete the quest for Farkas/Vilkas it should also complete the quest "talk to a companion leader" and then restart it, so you can get more quests.