# Already given a job by Farkas?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What job I was given by Farkas? I went to Farkas to get work but he and other members there keep saying that I have been already given a job by Farkas. I don't know the name of that job and so I can't find it in journal.

Comment: [Based on this](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Farkas) I would look for `Trouble in Skyrim`, `Proving Honor`, `Glory of the Dead`, `Purity`, or `Dragon Seekers`

Comment: Related: [Cannot Get a new Radiant Quest from Companions in Skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73395/4797) and [How can I advance the Companion's questline?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/120317/4797)

Comment: Related: [Companions Radiant Quests: No Quests Available?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/44700/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was related to threatening [Maramal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maramal). It was to be reported to Farkas. Completing it solved the issue

Comment: You should select your answer as the correct answer. You found it out after all!

Comment: The minimal description of journal entries are the culprit.